# How to make a bullet move towards a point in 3Dimensional space

Tags: java, math, 3d, lwjgl

I am currently making a 3D first person shooter with java LWJGL. I want to turn and move a bullet towards a specified point in the world. I managed to make the bullet turn on the Y-axis but not the X and Z. How can i make the bullet turn on the Z and X-axis and then move towards the point?

Here is my Bullet Class:

```
package entities;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import models.TexturedModel;
import renderEngine.DisplayManager;
import toolbox.MousePicker;

public class Bullet extends Entity{

private static Vector3f currentRay = new Vector3f();
private static final float RAY_RANGE = 600;
public static boolean reset = true;
public Bullet(TexturedModel model, Vector3f position, float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ, float scale) {
    super(model, position, rotX, rotY, rotZ, scale);

}
public void move(Bullet b){
    float distance =  2 * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
    currentRay = MousePicker.calculateMouseRay();
    Vector3f endPoint = MousePicker.getPointOnRay(currentRay, 10000);
    //I want my Bullet to move towards the Vector3f endPoint

    float zDistance = endPoint.z - this.getPosition().z;
    float xDistance = endPoint.x - this.getPosition().x;
    double angleToTurn = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(xDistance,     zDistance));
    this.setRotY((float)angleToTurn);
    float dx = (float) (distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(super.getRotY())));
    float dz = (float) (distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(super.getRotY())));

    super.increasePosition(dx, 0, dz);


}
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to get the 3 angles to rotate ?
Maybe you can consider setting the instant speed to :
targetPosition.sub(bulletPossition).normalize().scalarMult(bullet.maxSpeed)
And then adding this instant speed to the position on each update loop
(Sorry if the methods are not exactly the same provided by Vector3f, it's been a while for me :) ).

Comment: what is targetPostion?

Comment: Sorry, it's the point you called endPoint

Comment: scalarMult() doesn't want to work

Comment: maybe I'm getting it wrong. is bullet.maxSpeed a float?

Comment: the correct method is scale and not scalarMult but the idea is the same, multiply the normalized vector with some speed to get the instant speed (maybe you should also divide the speed by the number of FPS if the max speed of your bullet is in worldUnit per second).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is to get the speed required to make your bullet closer to your target (here the mouse) `endPoint`.

So first, you get the vector between the two `endPoint.sub(position);`

Then you `normalize()` it to get the direction.

You `scale()` it with your desired speed to get the instant speed.

and you `super.increasePosition(speed.x, speed.y, speed.z);` to make it move toward the target

Comment: Thanks so much! It finally worked after two months of frustration!

Comment: Perfect, can you close the post by validating my answer ? ;)